# Can i get real quick answer for find method in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, find

I need to find the last character using `find()` function, for example:

```
str = 'abcB+z'
```

`str.find('B+')` returns 4 which is the index of 'B' but I need the index of the character '+' (5) which is last character in the string passed to `find()`.

How can i do that?

Comment: I assume you asked about index of the last character of word, which you are searching in the string?
In this case: `str.find('B+') + len('B+') - 1`

Answer (score 0):

I always do:

```
end_index = text.find(pattern) + len(pattern)
```

in your case, substract 1 in the end.